# Return row's rowIndex on page load

Tags: javascript, indexing, html-table, row

I'm trying to print to page the rowIndex for each row in a table. I would like it to be placed inside the table itself, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>r1.cell1</td>
        <td>r1.cell2</td>
        <td><script>document.write("rowindex = " + this.parentNode.rowIndex);</script></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r2.cell1</td>
        <td>r2.cell2</td>
        <td><script>document.write("rowindex = " + this.parentNode.rowIndex);</script></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this in the context of execution of your script refers to the window object, not to the node. Must your solution be in pure JS or can you use library such as jQuery?

Comment: Louis, jQuery can be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery is a simple matter of doing it after the document is loaded. Assuming this is the only table in the whole page you could do something like

```
$('td:last-child').each(function(index, item) { $(item).html(index)})
```

You can see it in action using this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qurm4304/